# Descriptive statistics python for two sample test - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am looking to run describe() for a two sample test. I use `stats.ttest_rel` to get the t-stat and the p-value but I also need to generate std dev, mean etc. I could code for these using raw formulae but I was wondering if pandas, stats or numpy libraries have a function to do this. Thanks!

Comment: I found one way to do it. researchpy.ttest(csv_input_file['ROW'], csv_input_file['L'],
                            paired= True)

Comment: Now I am struggling with specifying the significance level. it seems to default to 0.05 and I am unable to find options to change that. Please help with that maybe?